# NavDropdown not opening after child item selected on mobile/tablet devices

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, responsive-design

I have a dropdown menu built using react-bootstrap. Current it doesn't open the second time after an option has been selected from the dropdown. The user needs to click off the menu somewhere for it to work again. It seems the menu is retaining a state from the initial click that mean it doesn't work second time round.

This only applies to mobile devices, it works fine on non-mobile devices.

See the code for the menu below:

```
            <NavDropdown
          onToggle={this.onToggle}
          onMouseEnter = { () => this.setState({ isOpen: true }) }
          onMouseLeave = { () => this.setState({ isOpen: false })  }
          open={ this.state.isOpen }
          noCaret
          eventKey={3}
          title="Account"
          id="nav-mega-dropdown"
        >
            <LinkContainer to="/app/account" onClick={() => this.setState({ isOpen: false })}><NavItem eventKey={3.1}>Public Profile</NavItem></LinkContainer>
            { this.props.isSupplier ? <LinkContainer to="/app/account/business" onClick={() => this.setState({ isOpen: false })}><NavItem eventKey={3.2}>Business Details</NavItem></LinkContainer> : null }

            <LinkContainer to="/app/account/schedule" onClick={() => this.setState({ isOpen: false })}><NavItem eventKey={3.3}>Schedule</NavItem></LinkContainer>
            { this.props.isSupplier ? <LinkContainer to="/app/account/users" onClick={() => this.setState({ isOpen: false })}><NavItem eventKey={3.4}>Users</NavItem></LinkContainer> : null }

            <LinkContainer to="/app/account/sessions" onClick={() => this.setState({ isOpen: false })}><NavItem eventKey={3.5}>Sessions</NavItem></LinkContainer>
            { this.props.isSupplier ? <LinkContainer to="/app/account/subscription" onClick={() => this.setState({ isOpen: false })}><NavItem eventKey={3.6}>Subscription</NavItem></LinkContainer> : null }

            <LinkContainer to="/app/account/locations" onClick={() => this.setState({ isOpen: false })}><NavItem eventKey={3.7}>Locations</NavItem></LinkContainer>
            <LinkContainer to="/app/account/settings" onClick={() => this.setState({ isOpen: false })}><NavItem eventKey={3.8}>Password</NavItem></LinkContainer>

            <LinkContainer to="/app/account/holidays" onClick={() => this.setState({ isOpen: false })}><NavItem eventKey={3.9}>Holidays</NavItem></LinkContainer>
            { this.props.isSupplier ? <LinkContainer to="/app/account/visibility" onClick={() => this.setState({ isOpen: false })}><NavItem eventKey={3.10}>Visibility</NavItem></LinkContainer> : null }

        </NavDropdown>
```